# Changing the value of an index inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, conditional-statements

I'm stuck with this problem where I need to eliminate a letter from each of the array values and change the first letter if it is in index 0. My current approach is this:

```
function capital(arr, char){
    let str = "";
    let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    str = arr[i] + (i < arr.length - 1 ? ",": "");;

    for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++){
        if (str[j] === char){
            result += "";
             if (str[j] === char){
            result += (j === 0? "A": "");
        }
        
        else {
            result += str[j];
        }
    }
}
    console.log(result);
}
capital(["doritos","sandking","bandana", "demand"], "d");
```

The program should eliminate each occurrence of letter d found in the strings and change the index 0 to letter A if the d is in index 0.

The current result is

> Aoritos,sanking,banana,Aeman

but it should look like

> Aritos,sanking,banana,Aman

The requirement does not allow any use of built in functions, and the actual program requires the letters to be case insensitive, but I can work on it by substituting codes and adding couple if elses, I just need help with the changing the index 0 condition. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: your example seems off to me, please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your input char is at first index `str.indexOf(char)` then simply add prefix `"A"` to your string `without first char` i.e `str.substring(1)`

```js
function capital(arr, char) {
  let str = "";
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str = arr[i];
    if(str.indexOf(char) === 0) {
      result = 'A' + str.substring(1);
    }else {
      result = str;
    }

    console.log(result);
  }
}
capital(["doritos", "sandking", "bandana", "demand"], "d");
```

Answer (score 0):

this logic may help you

```js
function capital(arr, char) {

  return arr.map(e => {

    let isFirst = false;
    if (e[0] == "d") isFirst = true;
    e = e.replace(new RegExp(char, 'ig'), '');
    if (isFirst)
      e = e.replace(e.charAt(0), "A");
    return e;
  });

}
console.log(capital(["doritos", "sandking", "bandana", "demand"], 'd'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each letter of your word and update the first letter if it is matched with passed letter and at 0 index, for other index if it doesn't match with passed letter add to your result.

```js
const capitalize = ch => {
 const letter = ch.charCodeAt(0);
 if(letter >= 97 && letter <= 122) {
    return String.fromCharCode(letter - 32);
 }
 return ch;
}

const capital = (words, ch) => {
  let result = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let newWord = '';
    for(let j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) {
      if(capitalize(words[i][j]) === capitalize(ch) && j === 0) {
        newWord = 'A';
      }
      if(capitalize(words[i][j]) !== capitalize(ch)) {
        newWord += words[i][j];
      }
    }
    result += newWord;
    if(i < words.length - 1 ) {
      result += ',';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const result = capital(["doritos","sandking","bandana", "demand", "sandDking"], "d");
console.log(result);
```